# Why can't I use WebRTC API in my ionic2 project which have added crosswalk plugin by cordova?

Tags: ionic2, webrtc, crosswalk

This is my plugins list:

- cordova-plugin-camera
- cordova-plugin-compat
- cordova-plugin-console
- cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview
- cordova-plugin-device
- cordova-plugin-splashscreen
- cordova-plugin-statusbar
- cordova-plugin-whitelist
- ionic-plugin-keyboard

and this is a part of my config.xml in root folder:

```
<plugin name="ionic-plugin-keyboard" spec="~2.2.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1.3.1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-console" spec="1.0.5" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="2.2.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="1.1.4" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="~4.0.1" />
```

I used command

```
cordova platform add android
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview
cordova build android --prod
```

to build my apk package and the package grow 20MB.
But when I use the WebRTC API, it throw a error that "RTCPeerConnection is not defined".
Why can't I use it? 
Should I add "plugin name="cordova-plugin-crosswalk" ..." into config.xml or ...?

Answer (score 0):

I had solved the question:
Just add "webkit" prefix on "RTCPeerConnection"。

Answer (score 0):

Using the `adapter.js` has my preference:

```
<script src="https://webrtc.github.io/adapter/adapter-latest.js"></script>
```